# How to send multi response using nusoap with soapval?

Tags: php, soap, soapui, nusoap

I am stuck in a situation where I am unable to send multi-response not array type using soapval(nusoap). I looking for a solution to make struct which accepts multi-request and send multi-response in nusoap. I saw a lot of examples where I only saw the response as an array this is the main issue I think so.

Let me show you my code

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'InitiateHolidayDataTransferResult',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'sequence',
    '',
    array( 'HOLIDAY_COMPLEX_TYPE_RES' => array(  
            'name' => 'HOLIDAY_COMPLEX_TYPE_RES',  'type' => 'tns:HOLIDAY_COMPLEX_TYPE_RES' ,'minOccurs' => '0', 'maxOccurs' => 'unbounded' )
)
);


$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'HOLIDAY_COMPLEX_TYPE_RES',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array( 'STATUS' => array('name' => 'STATUS','type' => 'xsd:string'),
           'STATUS_DESC' => array('name' => 'STATUS_DESC','type' => 'xsd:string')
));
```

```
// Register the method to expose
    $server->register('HOLIDAY_INFORMATION_DATA',                    // method name
    array('name' => 'tns:HOLIDAY_COMPLEX_TYPE_REQ'),          // input parameters
    array('return' => 'tns:HOLIDAY_COMPLEX_TYPE_RES'),    // output parameters
    'urn:HOLIDAY_SERVER1',                         // namespace
    'urn:HOLIDAY_SERVER1#HOLIDAY_INFORMATION_DATA',                   // soapaction
    'document',                                    // style
    'encoded',                                // use
    'Holiday Information Get Method'        // documentation
);
```

```
// Define the method as a PHP function
function HOLIDAY_INFORMATION_DATA($mycomplextype) {


    $holiday_data_success='';
// trying to send multi reponse in many ways see below
foreach($mycomplextype as $key=>$val){
//one way      
   $parm = array();
 $parm[] =  array('STATUS'=>"Success", "STATUS_DESC"=>"-Holiday Added");
 $parm[] =  array('STATUS'=>"Success", "STATUS_DESC"=>"-Holiday Added");
 $parm[] =  array('STATUS'=>"Success", "STATUS_DESC"=>"-Holiday Added");
 $holiday_data_success = new soapval('return', 'tns:HOLIDAYRES_COMPLEX_TYPE_RES', $parm);


//second way
        $arr = array("STATUS"=>"12345", "STATUS_DESC"=>"Test heading",);
        $arr2 = array("STATUS"=>"12346", "STATUS_DESC"=>"Test heading");
        $holiday_data_success = array($arr, $arr2);
 // third way
$holiday_data_success=[];
 $holiday_data_success[] =  new soapval('return', 'tns:InitiateHolidayRESTransferResult', array('STATUS'=>"Success", "STATUS_DESC"=>$successtr."-Holiday Added"));  

       } // end foreach






 return $holiday_data_success;
}
// but nothing is working
```

I am unable to send multi-response for each record that I insert in db

Comment: Too much code! Can you please [edit] your question and bring it down to a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes I can, let me edit it for you

Comment: What does this have to do with SoapUI?